# Magento 2: Error in magento2 product list when i have reviews with rating

Tags: error, magento2.2, fatal-error

I'm new developer and I'm trying to learn magento.
I have installed `Magento 2 CE` (with sample data, but I removed them and I have only a few products) on `Debian 9`.
The mode is the developer and I have activated debug

If I have review with rating, magento stop listing products at product which has rating and displays:

> [Sun Jun 24 10:05:56.838062 2018] [:error] [pid 2112] [client
>       192.168.1.2:61078] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getReviewsCount() on string in
>   /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/ReviewRenderer.php:97\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary_short.phtml(14):
>   Magento\Review\Block\Product\ReviewRenderer->getReviewsCount()\n#1
>   /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59):
>   include('/var/www/html/m...')\n#2
>   /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270):
>   Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Review\Block\Product\ReviewRenderer),
>   '/var/www/html/m...', Array)\n#3
>   /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/m...')\n#4
>   /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()\n#5
>   /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/ReviewRenderer.php(77):
>   in
>   /var/www/html/mg/vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/ReviewRenderer.php
>   on line 97, referer: http://debdev.loc/men.html

If I disable ratings, the product list appears normally with the link `"n reviews"` below its name.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I found what was the problem.
I started το uninstall extensions that I have installed.
One extension from git was responsible for previous error.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Thanks